# mathscr with tikzposter?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, tikzposter

I like to load `mathrsfs` in order to access supplementary letter shapes: the ones provided by `mathscr` are noticeably different than the ones produced by `mathcal`. But it doesn’t work well with `tikzposter`: the following document produces the warning “Font shape 'U/rsfs/m/n' in size <29.86> not available size <24.88> substituted on input line 9”, and indeed the `mathscr` letter appears too small.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.4}
        \block{Test}{
            $\mathcal{A}$ $\mathscr{A}$ $A$
        }
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Any idea if this problem can be solved or if a replacement for `mathrsfs` exists for this use case? (And, `mathrsfs` do not provide a bold version of these letters; it would be a plus if the proposed solution also avoids this problem.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `rsfso` provides scalable Type 1 version of RSFS fonts.

This seems to give a good result:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}

\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.4}
        \block{Test}{
            $\mathcal{A}$ $\mathscr{A}$ $A$
        }
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

@MarianG in a comment below shows how to use `\pmb` to fake bold math

Comment: Even better results can be obtained by loading the `amsbsy` package and using `$\pmb{\mathscr{A}}$`.

Comment: Great. Note that (as the manual explains) rsfso is not exactly the same font as mathrsfs: it is less slanted. (But this solves my problem adequately.)

Comment: @MarianG. -- `\pmb` creates a "bold" version of a glyph by overprinting three images slightly offset from one another.  This is hardly optimal, especially if it's going to be enlarged such as on a slide; if an alternate method is available, it's really preferable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You are right. Enlarged version can be annoying.